# Toast in the beginning of a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I wrote a thread that should inform the user of being started.

```
@Override           
public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    printToast(START_PRINT + fileName + "...");
    Bundle b = mCallback.onSendFile();
```

Where:
fileName is global String.
START_PRINT is final String

The printToast is a function that calls the method: Toast.makeText like this:

```
void printToast(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have another toast in the end of the thread.
Now i can't understand why the i can't see the first toast and i see only the second one.
Please help!
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your full `run()` method? I'd also try creating a UI-Thread Handler and posting to that as opposed to using a Looper.

Comment: Sorry misread the question.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare/16886486#16886486 In short, you need to call toaster functions from the UI thread.